# hi i have a problem with dht11 and LED

Tags: raspbian, led, temperature, dht22, power-light

I want to record data from dht11 and turn on the LED in the same code
the dht11 work good by separate code
the led also work well by separate code the problem is when I make it one py code problem become with error

ValueError: A different mode has already been set!

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have two or more calls to `GPIO.setmode()`.

You should only have one call to `GPIO.setmode()`.

If one is using `GPIO.BOARD` and one is using `GPIO.BCM` you will have to choose one and amend the code to use that GPIO numbering scheme.

Comment: first, I use import RPi.GPIO as gpio and import RPi.GPIO as gpio when I add import adafruit_dht it gives ValueError: ValueError: A different mode has already been set! ... any suggestion ??

Comment: The Adafruit module is setting a different mode to that set in the other script.